# Install an application and database for all users

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to use the latest inno setup to deploy my program. It seems I can't (and not recommended) to install my program to Program Files folder due to the restrictions it's going to give (for example my program will always have problem using the part of the program which modifies database, unless it's started as an admin). I read somewhere that we should ask inno setup to install our program at `CSIDL_APPDATA` but i'm not really well versed with inno setup. How do I do this using Inno setup?

Comment: Probably you misunderstood what you read and in fact it might be suggesting to deploy your data files at CSIDL_APPDATA and your program to program files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The application itself should be installed into a folder underneath `{pf}` (Program Files).
Application data (or a database) however should go into a folder underneath `{commonappdata}`. If the database is to be modified by normal users, then you'll need to set the permissions on this folder (using the `Permissions` parameter). If it's user specific, they can copy the default to the user's appdata folder and modify that.

```
[Dirs]
Name: {commonappdata}\i-Catcher Console; permissions: everyone-modify admins-full;
```

The complication comes when using an Access application that has the UI built into the database itself. In this case both locations are just as bad as each other (`{commonappdata}/blah` is marginaly better) but you will need to set the permissions as appropriate.

Comment: but if I put the database and the application into different folder, it will create problems since in my c# code I just use String connString = "Data Source=recipes.db"; which means the recipes.db should reside in the same folder as the main executable, no?

Comment: That will fail under various situations anyway. You should fix it to determine the application data folder and use a fully qualified path.

Comment: emmm.. how do I do that in c#? i mean something like String connString = "Data Source=" + installedfolder +"recipes.db"

Comment: In C#, you can get the path using something like: `string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + @"\i-Catcher Console\Logs\";`. As I said in my reply, you should not use the installation path for the database.

Comment: Unless you absolutely need the database to be shared by multiple user accounts (which isn't all that common) you should install only a read-only template in `{app}` or `{commonappdata}`, and make the application itself make a copy of this in its `{userappdata}` equivalent path for actual use, if not already present.  While there are some situations where permissions changes are required, they should be avoided if at all possible, as they inherently reduce security in one way or another.

Comment: @Miral Feel free to update my answer :) I will at some point if not.